# Finding the minimum value of an expression

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Where $n = 5$, $a = 1$, $b = 2$ and $x + y = n$ i.e. $x + (n- x) = n$,what is the minimum number that can be had from $ax^2 + by^2$ by using differentiation?

I know the answer is 17 from doing it manually:

$ 1 \times 0^2+ 2 \times 5^2= 50 $

$ 1 \times 1^2+ 2 \times 4^2= 33 $ 

$ 1 \times 2^2+ 2 \times 3^2= 22 $ 

$ 1 \times 3^2+ 2 \times 2^2= 17 $

$ 1 \times 4^2+ 2 \times 1^2= 18 $

$ 1 \times 5^2+ 2 \times 0^2= 25 $

Comment: Your arithmetic is mostly wrong.  $1\times 2^2+2\times 3^2=4+18=22$.   and $1\times 3^2+2\times 2^2=9+8=17$, for example.

Comment: If $x,y$ are constrained to be integers then differentiation just gets you near to the solution.  Here you can use Lagrange Multipliers to see that $y=\frac ab x$, so in this case the true min would occur at $(\frac {10}3, \frac 53)$.  You then have to test the nearby integers to see which is the integer min.

Answer (score 0):

Since $y = n-x$,
$ax^2+by^2
=ax^2+b(n-x)^2
=(a+b)x^2-2bnx+bn^2
=f(x)
$.

$f'(x)
=2(a+b)x-2bn
=0$
when
$x
=\dfrac{bn}{a+b}
$.

For this,
$n-x
=n-\dfrac{bn}{a+b}
=\dfrac{an}{a+b}
$
so
$f(x)
=ax^2+b(n-x)^2
=a\dfrac{b^2n^2}{(a+b)^2}+b\dfrac{a^2n^2}{(a+b)^2}
=\dfrac{ab^2n^2+ba^2n^2}{(a+b)^2}
=\dfrac{abn^2(b+a)}{(a+b)^2}
=\dfrac{abn^2}{a+b}
$.

Since
$f''(x)
=2(a+b)
\gt 0$,
this is a minimum.

Nothing fancy.

For your case,
$x 
= \dfrac{1\ 2\ 5^2}{1+2}
= \dfrac{50}{3}
=16\frac23
$.

To find an integer min,
which is not stated in your question,
look at
the integers
surrounding this value
if it is not an integer.
It is probably the integer
closest to this,
but I have not tried to prove this.

In your case,
these are 16 and 17.,
with 17 being closer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking for the minimum value of $f(x,y) = x^2+2y^2$ subject to the constraint, $g(x,y)=x+y-5=0$ with $x$ and $y$ real? The minimum occurs at the point $x=10/3, y=5/3$ and at this point $f$ takes value $f(10/3,5/3)=50/3<17$. One way this “critical point” can be found is by setting the gradient of $F(x,y,\mu) = f+\mu g$ equal to zero, i.e. $\nabla F= 0$.